# Disassemble ELF to asm and assemble to ELF again

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, elf

Let say I am running a box on x86 or x86_64 and have an executable/library in the Executable- and Linkable Format (ELF). Would it be possible to

1. generate an assembler listing from the ELF and then
2. assemble it back to an ELF again?

If yes,

- are there any tools that do that (the first step)?
- is it possible to produce an ELF that is bitwise identical to the original one? If not, how close could one be to the perfect case?

Comment: This seems very tough to achieve, mainly because disassembling is a lossy procedure. Many sections of the ELF file can't be understood and are either discarded or converted to some kind of raw data. If binary similitude to the original file is your goal, the classic way is to look at the usual disassembly, write changes, assemble them separately or by hand and then patch the original binary.

Comment: You might also want to check out http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/